# ASP.NET MVC3 Entity with ViewModel CRUD pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm using EF with ViewModel and AutoMapper design strategies for an MVC3 application.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of creating the CRUD pages then what I'm currently doing.

My Current Process Involves:

- Create the Entity
- Create the ViewModel via copy paste then deleted non-required fields
- Add the Entity to the Context list
- Create a controller via the Visual Studio 2010 create controller *wizard* page.
- I select a Template of Controller with read write actions and views, using Entity Framework.
- I choose my model to be my ViewModel instead of my entity.
- I select the appropriate context.
- **Now the part I part I think can be improved**, I have to re-write all the CRUD methods to use AutoMapper and the Entity/ViewModel design pattern changing:

`return View(db.BlockedUserViewModels.ToList());`

into:

```
IList<BlockedUser> blockedUsers = db.BlockedUsers.ToList();
IList<BlockedUserViewModel> blockedUserVMs = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<BlockedUser>, IList<BlockedUserViewModel>>(blockedUsers);
return View(blockedUserVMs);
```

- I have to add the same [Authorize] and roles permissions to each controller CRUD option.

This seems way overkill in workload! I'm hoping there a better solution. (I'm coming from Python/Django where it requires a single line of code to create beautiful strong CRUD pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can add a service and inject it into your controller. Then you only have to call

```
var model = _service.GetBlockedUsers();
```

each time instead of:

```
IList<BlockedUser> blockedUsers = db.BlockedUsers.ToList();
IList<BlockedUserViewModel> blockedUserVMs = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<BlockedUser>, IList<BlockedUserViewModel>>(blockedUsers);
```

This will keep your controllers light and act as a place to keep your crud logic so you don't have to repeat it everywhere.

Also, you can add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller if it applies to every action in the controller.

Comment: Good point, I overlooked the easy solution looking for a package to provide this for me. Is it appropriate to put these utility methods inside the context? Thanks for the tip about the controller [Authorize] Attribute, unfortunately they are not consistent.

Comment: It depends on your implementation. I use the repository pattern with my entities so they manage the CRUD operations and my services are just wrappers around my repositories that map the entities to their associated view models.

Comment: Know of a tutorial / example of what your describing? I've read mention about the repository feature but don't fully understand the benefits of the added layer of complexity

Comment: I use my own slightly modified implementation of the repository pattern discussed [here](http://efmvc.codeplex.com). The only real reason to introduce the repository pattern with EF 4.1 is to make your DAL mockable for unit testing. Other than that, its basically just extra overhead.

Comment: Not quite the solution I was hoping for, but the best answer in terms of helping me move forward quicker, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how painful this is for you, but you can always use the MVC scaffolding stuff found in Nuget and written by Steven Sanderson. Investing some time could help you in the long run, but you have to figure out if it's right for you.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Comment: I've looked at this briefly before, it definitely seems capable of doing what I'm looking for, but I'd need to write the scaffolder from scratch. There must be someone out there who has done the work for scaffolding with AutoMapper and supplied there code!

Comment: There possibly might be, but writing your own will make it easier to deal with the differences in your code vs. someone else.